# C# Class Library include images

Tags: c#, class-library

I've got a C# class library that I want to be able to use an image. How do I include an image in the class library and reference it (in the class library), guaranteeing that there won't be any errors accessing the image no matter what is using the class library (web app, desktop application, etc)?

Comment: Embed the image as a resource. Expose the resource via a property or method defined in the class-library.